# Is there an engine-agnostic tool for editing curve animations?

Tags: 3d, animation, tools

I am looking for a tool that allows to edit 3D animation curves. What I want is something similar to how the animation system works in Unity or others. Being able to create a timeline of transformations to some object, with properties like scaling, rotation, position etc.

I am looking for an engine agnostic tool that can export this in a format that can be parsed and used in my own engine, like some level editors do.